# How to get Google Analytics to track progress through a multi-page Drupal Webform?

Tags: webforms, google-analytics

I've got a couple of complex multipage webforms, and want to track progress through these forms so that I can how much time users are spending on each page, and whether there are particular pages that cause users to drop out altogether. I thought Google Analytics could do the trick, but it seems to require a unique URL for each page, and that's something that the Webform module doesn't provide.

Has anyone got this to work, and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

if the url doesn't change, you can use google's single page applications approach to track:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

You can set a "virtual" url for each page using javascript. Then create a goal funnel in Google Analytics using these virtual url's. You'll probably need to custom write this js to look for specific fields etc to let it know which page it's on.

I think another way is to use custom fields in the call to ga. Not sure if those are available as goals though.